# not recognized cas ticket

Tags: single-sign-on, cas

I have a REST api in my web application where I get cas ticket generated by another webapp.

That webapp intern use `cas20proxyticketvalidator` to validate the ticket. Therefore, I also use `Cas20ProxyTicketValidator` in my custom filter to validate the ticket.

But it always give me following error:

```
ticket = ST-148008-jWXKeEdHkxmuktvYqXF6-cas
org.jasig.cas.client.validation.TicketValidationException:
                ticket 'ST-148008-jWXKeEdHkxmuktvYqXF6-cas' not recognized

        at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator.parseResponseFromServer(Cas20ServiceTicketValidat
or.java:86)
        at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java
:217)
```

Why my ticket is not recognized?

Answer (score 11):

The way that cas validates tickets is:

1. Your client (or the other web app) requests a ticket from the relay
   server for a particular service, for example case
   http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebapp.com
2. The cas server generates a row that stores the user's ssoguid, the service and the ticket. It returns the ticket to the client (or
   other web app)
3. The client (or other webapp) sends the ticket to your server
4. Your server then sends a request to the serviceValidate endpoint of the cas server with the ticket and the service,
   http%3A%2F%2Fmywebapp.com
5. The cas server uses the ticket and service pair to find the row it generated. If it finds the row it: a) checks to see if the
   service is real by sending a request to that url b) deletes the row
   to invalidate the ticket after this validation check c) it returns
   the user attached to the ticket to your server. Now the ticket can
   not be validated again.

The problem you are experiencing could arise for several reasons:

1. The ticket has already been validated (I don't think that is the
   case for you)
2. **The service you send when generating the ticket is different to the service you send to the serviceValidate endpoint (they have to
   be identical). (I would guess that this is the problem you are
   experiencing, especially if another webapp generated the ticket. The
   cas server would have http%3A%2F%2Fotherwebapp.com on file but would
   be trying to find a row with http%3A%2F%2Fmywebapp.com, which
   doesn't exist because you didn't create it)**
3. The service sent can
   not be contacted by the relay server (I'm not exactly sure of the
   details about how this works or exactly when the check it done but
   it is recommended that you use a service that can be contacted)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the ticket was expiring before validation. Default expiry of service ticket is 10s.

Answer (score 0):

Check the **serviceUrl generated**, so change the log level for package org.jasig.

With SpringBoot, in the application.properties add

```
logging.level.org.jasig=DEBUG
```

In the console

```
org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils : serviceUrl generated: https://xxx
```

Verify and adapt your **cas.client-host-url** in the application.properties

```
## CAS[2.0]
cas.server-url-prefix=https://cashost.com/cas
cas.server-login-url=https://cashost.com/cas/login
cas.client-host-url=xxx
cas.validation-type=CAS
```

Be careful with cas.client-host-url, no slash at the end of url.

Don't forget **mvn clean package** after modifying .properties